# NVM for windows error after installing nodejs

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm completely new to nodejs and nvm , I installed nvm latest version and installed two nodejs versions.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm list 
10.10.0 
08.12.0
```

I'm getting this error when I try to use nodejs

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm use 10.10.0
 exit status 1: 'C:\Users\iClick' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Both nodejs folders are sitting inside nvm folder at

```
C:\Users\iClick Digital\AppData\Roaming\nvm
```

and these are system env var paths

```
NVM_Home C:\Users\iClick Digital\AppData\Roaming\nvm
NVM_SYMLINK C:\Programe Files/nodejs
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the space in your username, try setting `NVM_HOME` to a path with no space.

Comment: I installed Nodist and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I recommend removing `nvm` and using the `n` package instead. You can find more information about `n` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n). In my experience, `nvm` has had issues, especially on Linux. On the other hand, `n` is more stable and very easy to install, uninstall, and use.
In short, you just need to run the following commands:

1. `npm i -g n`
2. `n 18.16.0` (or replace `18.16.0` with the version you want, event just `n lts`)